# Option menu in Android like a Windows 8 phone

Tags: android, menu, slidingmenu

I am trying to implement a menu just like in Windows 8 phone. When I touch three dots menu bar button, it slides up and shows other options. I saw a sliding drawer in Android, but it is deprecated in API 17. I searched on Google but did not find solution. Any ideas on how I could implement this?

You can see a picture of the menu view.

[image]

Comment: Take a look on how is implemented SlidingMenu lib by Jeremy Feinstein for some inspiration: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: A similar pattern is implemented in the [AndroidSlidingUpPanel library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). You may find that helpful as a starting point, although it will need some customizations.

Comment: hi , want to implement the same .Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in many ways. I.e. by using `RelativeLayout` as main container and separate i.e. `LinearLayout` as your menu container. And you then show/hide your menu container when you need. And you can apply animation to container.

Comment: I got your point and i tried to implement it but i am not getting what i want. Can you elaborate this.